# Getting response text from node fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, node-fetch

I'm fairly new to node fetch and I'm doing a simple get request to get a list of my postman collections. I'm able to get the response text and console log it in the function
but when I'm returning the responseText to a variable and logging it, I get an empty result,could someone suggest why?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function getCollections() {
  var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "X-Api-Key",
    "<API-KEY>"
  );
  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
  };
  url = "https://api.getpostman.com/collections";
  const requestResponse = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  const response = await requestResponse.text();
  return response;
}

const result = getCollections();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're not awaitng getCollections() in your result varaible. Should be: const reuslt = await getCollections(); That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are logging `result` before the async function has a chance to return the resolved promise. I can think of two ways to resolve this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function getCollections() {
  var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "X-Api-Key",
    "<API-KEY>"
  );
  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
  };
  url = "https://api.getpostman.com/collections";
  const requestResponse = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  const response = await requestResponse.text();
  return response;
}

getCollections().then(console.log);
```

Or moving the console log inside the asynchronous function.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function getCollections() {
  var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "X-Api-Key",
    "<API-KEY>"
  );
  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
  };
  url = "https://api.getpostman.com/collections";
  const requestResponse = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  const response = await requestResponse.text();
  console.log(response)
  return response;
}

getCollections()
```